# Deal with Squid Kerberos auth and Squidguard ldapusersearch

Tags: linux, ldap, kerberos, squid

I'm meeting troubles with Squid Kerberos auth and the Squidguard ldapusersearch who I use to apply acl by Active Directory groups membership.

The problem is :

- Squid and Squidguard see my user as : `user@domain.local` so **the '%s' variable of squidguard is `'user@domain.local'`**
- Into my ldap query there is no default property who can interpret this string.

Example :

```
src ldap {
        ldapusersearch ldap://dc1.domain.local:3268/dc=domain,dc=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(&(sAMAccountName=%s)(memberOf=CN=group,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=local))
}
```

**And sAMAccountName should be only `'user'` and not `'user@domain.local'` !!!**

So I found a solution but It's not very comfortable :

I edit a unused attribute of the AD user and I write into it my kerberos login so my conf looks like this :

```
src ldap {
        ldapusersearch ldap://dc1.domain.local:3268/dc=domain,dc=local?displayNamePrintable?sub?(&(displayNamePrintable=%s)(memberOf=CN=group,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=local))
}
```

And it works !!!

Anyone an idea to bypass the need to create a custom attribute in AD who contents ?

I precise that `userPrincipalName` is the same as the email and can't interpret Kerberos login.

Thanks all !!!

Comment: Thank you very much artmees ! This is more clear like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am using Squid Version 3.4.5-20140514-r13135 with squidguard 1.5-beta and the strip-domain-realm Patch of Mathieu Parent which is able to strip the Domain and Strip the Realm.
So the users appear as "user" and not as "user@KERBEROSDOMAIN"

Here is an exmaple configuration thats working for me

---

dbhome /var/lib/squidGuard/db
logdir /var/log/squidGuard

ldapbinddn      squidguard@domain.tld
ldapbindpass    squidguardpass
ldapprotover    3
ldapcachetime   2400

stripntdomain true
striprealm true

src users {
        ldapusersearch "ldap://ldapserver:3268/dc=ADDomain,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(&(sAMAccountName=%s)(memberOf=CN=SQUID_USERS,OU=Squid_Groups,OU=Groups,DC=ADDomain,DC=com))"
        }